# Namenode starting but Datanode not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I get the following exception when I start the distributed file system. I am using hadoop 2.6.0.

```
    2015-08-26 23:10:58,222 FATAL datanode.DataNode (DataNode.java:secureMain(2385)) - Exception in secureMain
    java.net.UnknownHostException: IM1948-X0: IM1948-X0
            at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getLocalHostName(SecurityUtil.java:187)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:207)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2153)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2202)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2378)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2402)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: IM1948-X0
            at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
            at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
2015-08-26 23:10:58,227 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1
2015-08-26 23:10:58,229 INFO  datanode.DataNode (StringUtils.java:run(659)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: IM1948-X0: IM1948-X0
```

Even deleting the hadoop/hdfs-data/current directory doesnot help; I tried formatting the namenode but without success. This generally happens to me when I restart hadoop.

Basically to sum up, datanode process is not running at all for the hadoop cluster.

Comment: check if `hostname -f` command is providing a valid fully qualified domanname(fqdn) on the machine. And you need to set your local dns to point IP to this fqdn in /etc/hosts file

Comment: hostname and "hostname -f" provides the same domain name. How to verify if its a fully qualified domain name